# Minecraft Mod Won't Launch

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Whenever I run the minecraft mod instead of minecraft opening this is what happens. I do not know why my code won't run I think it's something with not being able to find the minecraft folder perhaps

```
[2021-05-16 12:06:29] [INFO   ] Natives: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Minecraft Mod Maker\forge-1.12.2- 
14.23.5.2855-mdk\build\natives 
[2021-05-16 12:06:29] [INFO   ] Main Class: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch 
[2021-05-16 12:06:29] [INFO   ] Srg2Mcp: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Minecraft Mod Maker\forge-1.12.2- 
14.23.5.2855-mdk\build\createSrgToMcp\output.srg 
[2021-05-16 12:06:29] [INFO   ] Extra: [] 
[2021-05-16 12:06:29] [INFO   ] Running with arguments: [--version, 1.12, --assetIndex, 1.12, -- 
assetsDir, C:\Users\danut\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --accessToken, {REDACTED}, -- 
userProperties, [], --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker] 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
 atjava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot 
be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and 
java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
... 6 more
```

Comment: Check your Java version, looks like you're trying to build with a version higher than Java 8 (1.8). If you are, use Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mod list and make sure that your mods are up to date. I also recommend using a higher version of Minecraft as it is more stable. Some mods might be conflicting, because they use the same variable names or something similar. Try to remove the mods one-by-one until it works and add the mods that works before back in.

**Examples:**

- Optifine
- DecoCraft
- Dynamic Trees(hypothetically don't work with Optifine)
- Dynamic Surroundings

**Step 1:**

- remove Dynamic Surroundings

**Step 2:**

- remove Dynamic Trees
- It works!!!

**Step 3:**

- put Dynamic Surroundings back in the mod list to test if it works.

Comment: I downvoted because this answer doesn't answer the question.  The question clearly states "I do not know why my code won't run," indicating that the OP is the one writing the mod.  Removing the mod is not a way to get the mod to run.